# how to retrieve an associated value from an enum

Tags: swift

i have a tree data structure that holds an associated value, currently when called it only returns the full tree, im trying to access individual values from the values. I've tried using an if let to pattern match but it didn't work out.

```
public indirect enum BinaryTree<T> {
    //left child, value, right child

    case node( BinaryTree<T>, T,T,T, BinaryTree<T>)
    case empty
    }

extension BinaryTree: CustomStringConvertible {
    public var description: String {
        switch self {
        case let .node(left, value, answer1, answer2, right):
            return " \(value) \(answer1) \(answer2) \(left.description) \(right.description)"
        case .empty:
            return ""
        }
    }
}





let node4 = BinaryTree.node(.empty, "4","A","B", .empty)
let node5 = BinaryTree.node(.empty, "5","A","B", .empty)
let node6 = BinaryTree.node(.empty, "6","A","B",.empty)
let node7 = BinaryTree.node(.empty, "7","A","B",.empty)




// intermediate nodes on the left
let fourtwofive = BinaryTree.node(node4, "2","A","B",node5)


// intermediate nodes on the right
let sixthreeeseven = BinaryTree.node(node6, "3","A","B",node7)

// root node
let tree = BinaryTree.node(fourtwofive, "1","A","B",sixthreeeseven)
```

how do i get value, answer1, and answer2 out of the enum

Comment: Where exactly do you want to get the values out of the enum?

Answer (score 0):

You are working with associated values, not tuples. With that in mind, as you inferred you would like to extract the values with `if let`, this would work:

```
if case let .node(_, value, answer1, answer2, _) = tree {
    // process value, answer1 and answer2
}
```